# Problems with Javascript code in html file

Tags: javascript, html

Code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.3.1.js">
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
      alert("Hello World");
    });
  </script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link href="../style/Home.css">
</head>

<body>
  <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" id="user" />
  <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" id="pass" />
  <input type="submit" id="submitButton">
</body>
```

The html section of the code, like the input fields works fine, but the javascript portion has not been working. Originally I had it where the javascript portion of the code was its own separate file, but I ultimately had to change that when it wasn't working. Even after I added the javascript code to the html file the code still wouldn't run, so I just did a generic alert statement to see if the problem was with the javascript code or if it was something else.

Comment: Just type `alert('Hello World')` inside the script tag nothing else.

Comment: Use the [browser console (dev tools)](//webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and read any errors. What is the problem? Is the `alert` working or not? What is the non-working code? Your question seems quite incomplete.

Comment: Unrelated note: `<meta charset="utf-8">` should be the *first* thing you put inside the `<head>`. Put it as early as possible so that the browser knows right away what charset to use.

Answer (score -1):

in you browse press F12 > Network > make sure Disable cache has checked

you should type alert() only

```
<script>
   alert();
</script>
```

alert will still run even if jquery is not read

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code in the question.

Comment: I don't think there's anything wrong with the script!

Answer (score -3):

path to your jquery file is invalid.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.3.1.js">
```

in src, you cannot give path like this: jquery-3.3.1.js.
give proper path.

Comment: There's absolutely nothing wrong with that path, it's just referring to a file in the same directory as the current page.